# Run Blustacks or Android to play clash of clans on ubuntu 13.4+

Tags: virtualbox, wine, games, android, virtualization

I am trying to get rid of the need to dual boot Ubuntu and windows and one thing I can do with windows I can not do with Linux is to run Bluestacks to play android games my favourite one ow is clash of clans. I have tried different VM's to run android emulators and virtual box but nothing works for clash of clans I can download the game to the VM from Google Play Store but it fails to open

If Ubuntu can fix this by making a way to successfully install Bluestacks on Ubuntu or Android with Virtual box with out loading errors of all apps/games it would help the Linux community to become less dependant of Windows.

Thanks in advance! go Ubuntu!

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: I want to play Android apps and games Pacifically Clash of CLans on Ubuntu

Comment: I also tried Running Windows 7 with Virtual box and then Bluestacks within the Windows VM but still loading error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install VirtualBox Install virtualbox from the Ubuntu Software Center.

download android sdk to run AVD

Create a new Virtual Machine with the steps mentioned here.
http://androvm.org/blog/blog/2012/11/14/androvm-configuration-tutorial/

download ur app and run

------------------OR--------------
(BEST=>)Try Genymotion runs with VBox/ Linux 
Its not really bluestacks but something similar which will emulate android apps
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2333452

Comment: Bluestacks does not work in VirtualBox; it complains that the graphics card is unrecognized and refuses to install.

Clash of Clans does not work on GenyMotion.

Answer (score -1):

Use Wine Application to run it on Ubuntu. It can run any app of windows in Ubuntu. You can Download it from Software center.
USe he virtual box. For more information check out[enter link description here](http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Run-Android-Applications-on-Ubuntu-115152.shtml)

Comment: Wine does not work for Bluestacks unless you or someone else got it to work i couldnt thanks i wish it was that easy

Comment: Every version of Bluestacks has a "garbage" quality rating for wine: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=13717